# Bootstrap header: button before brand

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, nav

This is what I've tried:

```
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="btn btn-default navbar-btn pull-left" href="">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">Some text</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
```

And a plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/NDp3R5XKxTgKAe0Ez7Js/preview

The problem is that the gap between the button and text is present only if i resize the window:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq5pJ.png

What is the right way to place a button before bootstrap navbar-brand?
I can't find any examples.

Comment: Please include the relevant code and images within the question. Just giving links to other sites means the question is not self-contained and will be of no use to others if the off-site items are changed or deleted.

Comment: Sorry for that, the question was edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default, if you put your `.navbar` in a `.container` or `.container-fluid`, `.navbar-brand` will have a `margin-left` of `-15px`. So do this to fixed  it. Add this css.

```
.navbar>.container .navbar-brand, .navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

I think this is because brand is typically the first item in a navbar.

Comment: This did the job. Thank you very much.